# Alterar tabela com javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, table, tabela-html

Possuo uma tabela de pedido criada dinamicamente, o usuário seleciona o item, a quantidade, e se é para empréstimo ou não, e adiciona o item na tabela.

Eu precisava que, ao adicionar novamente um item que já está inserido na tabela (por exemplo o mouse, cujo ID é 8) e que a coluna empréstimo também possua o mesmo valor, ao invés de adicionar uma nova linha para o mouse, aumentar a quantidade da linha já existente na tabela, e eu não sei como fazer.

Então eu preciso, ao adicionar um novo produto, verificar todas as linhas da tabela na coluna de ID's se já existe o ID desse produto que está sendo inserido e se a coluna EMPRESTIMO dessa linha também possui o mesmo valor da que está sendo inserida, se as 2 condições forem verdadeiras, ao invés de adicionar uma nova linha, apenas aumentar a quantidade da linha já existente.

```
<table id="tabela_pedido">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Quantidade</th>
   <th>Empréstimo</th>
   <th>Ações</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <td style="display:none;">8</td>
 <td>Mouse</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>Sim</td>
 <td><button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Onde: a primeira coluna que está escondida é o ID do item, a segunda o nome, a terceira a quantidade que está sendo pedida, a terceira se é um item para empréstimo ou não, e a quarta uma ação para remover a linha

Comment: Que tipo de dados você está trabalhando? Digo, os dados do produto

Comment: é um produto que possui ID, nome, quantidade em estoque. e no pedido é inserido o ID do produto e a quantidade solicitada

Comment: OK, mas como você faz o controle dos produtos selecionados? Com array? Ou só adiciona na tabela?

Comment: só adicionei na tabela

Comment: Você poderia tentar usar o DataTables para isso e ainda pode incrementar sua tabela com as funcionalidades de busca, ordenação, etc. https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Answer (score -1):

No seu caso seria melhor controlar os produtos selecionados com um array de objetos, por exemplo:

```
var produtos = [
    { id: 0, nome: "lorem", valor: 0 },
    { id: 1, nome: "lorem 1", valor: 0 },
    { id: 2, nome: "lorem 2", valor: 0 } 
];
```

E os produtos selecionados:

```
var selecionados = [
    { id: 1, quantidade: 2, emprestimo: true },
    { id: 2, quantidade: 1, emprestimo: false },
];
```

Quando fosse adicionar um novo produto na lista, verificaria pelo id se já está na lista, nesse caso somente adiciona em 1 o valor da propriedade 'quantidade' do elemento. Ex.

```
var id = 1; // id do produto selecionado    
var encontrado = selecionados.find(function(el) {
                     return el.id === id;
                 }); // busca o produto
if (encontrado)
    encontrado.quantidade++;
```

Depois apenas exiba na tabela os valores percorrendo o array.

Comment: oi, eu acabei fazendo várias coisas desde a hora que fiz a pergunta, agora estou obtendo um array com todas as linhas da tabela, estou tentando fazer algo para percorrer este array e somar as quantidades dos produtos repetidos, deletando-os após isso.

    $item[0]['id']
    $item[0]['quantidade']

estou obtendo um array assim ...